# Example about not unique Hahn-Banach extension

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M$ be the subespace of $\ell_1 = \{ \xi = (\xi_n) \subseteq \mathbb{K} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\xi_n| < \infty \}$ defined by $M = \{ (\xi_n) \in \ell_1 : \xi_{2n} = 0 ~\text{para}~ n = 1, 2, \dotsc \}$; and $\ell'_1$ denotes the dual of $\ell_1$.
I'm trying to look for an example of a bounded linear functional $f: M \longrightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that there exist at least two different functionals $f_1$, $f_2$ of $\ell'_1$ with $f_{j|M} = f$ and $||f_j|| = ||f||$ for $j = 1, 2, \dotsc$ (i.e., such that $f$ admits at least two different extensions to $\ell_1$). Does this contradict the Hahn-Banach Theorem?

Could someone help me?, please.

Thanks

Comment: When is your homework due? Do you know what is the dual of $\ell_1$? It would be extremely useful to know, in this context. Then ask yourself, which linear functionals vanish on your subspace, whence the solution to your exercise will follow quite easily.

Comment: It doesn’t contradict Hahn-Banach because it is not asking for $f$ to be sublinear.